# Fingering Advice for Bach Invention 13

Tags: piano, fingering

I was hoping to get some feedback about my choice of fingering shown in the picture below.

[image: Invention 13 fingering]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fingering isn't bad. I compared it to an ancient Willis Edition I have that my dad got me way back when... (It cost $1.75 oh so many years ago!) and you are pretty close to that in most places, however, I'd like to point out some things you might find helpful.

Keep in mind that this fingering works for me, and it may not work for you. Also keep in mind that the purpose of fingering, in many cases, is to align your hand for a new position. The in between notes should fit the hand simply without difficulty, while other fingers are then being used to pivot the hands and direct them in a particular direction so the performer can get his or her hand ready for the next place on the keyboard.

This is something that really needs attention, especially, in Bach and Scarlatti, as well other Baroque and Classical period music, and it definitely works well in Chopin too. Remember Chopin studied a lot of Bach and Mozart!

Anyway, back to your fingering, which I've seemed to have moved bit off topic from...

1st measure:

RH: Use a 1 on the G-sharp as this gets your hand shaped to hit the E above with the 5 finger.

LH: Is okay. Coming down with a 2 on the A is fine since it's an end of the phrase and you are moving your hand slightly to hit the E below with your 5th finger.

2nd measure: OK

3rd measure:

You need to open your hand up a bit. Playing cramped doesn't give you room to move as this measure splits and runs upwards very quickly so...

Try this instead (copied from my Willis Edition)

RH: 5 4 instead of a 4 2, use a 2 4 instead of a 1 4 (opens up the hand), the rest is okay

LH: Try this instead... 1 2 3 1 3 1 4 (a combination of yours and mine here).

4th measure: OK

5th measure:

Try this for the LH:

5 3 2 1 5 3 2 1 3 1

6th measure in C-maj.:

LH: 5 then 5 to start the move upwards. Remember this is a phrase end and a short breath will give you a chance to change positions quickly.

The rest is okay.

You've got the idea here, let us know how you make out on this and of course as more questions.

Comment: Thank you. I was actually using 5 4 on 3rd measure RH, but changed it to 4 2 to make it consistent with measures 4,5, and 6. I was making a lot of mistakes and then I re-did the fingering with the aim of maximizing consistency -- hoping that would reduce mistakes.

Comment: Consistency is one of the best things with fingering. I find that this is then one less thing to remember making the music learning and playing process easier. :-)